# How can I extend a redstone signal along a line while powering everything below it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I need to power everything below the redstone's path, but placing a repeater leads to the block below not being powered. How could I solve that without using a repeater to skip a block?

Comment: Your question could use with some formatting/grammar fixes, but I think I understand what you are asking. IANAE by any means with redstone in minecraft, so this could be completely wrong, but could use you use a redstone block instead of dust?

Comment: But how would he unpower it?(with pistons?). Also, his "bad grammar" might be because he is no a native speaker, as I see that here all the time.

Comment: Could you add a few more details on what exactly you are trying to do? A screen shot of what you have so far would be very helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

At the 13th block of redstone, place one redstone piece to the side, place one repeater in front of it, and reconnect it at the 15th block of redstone, like so. (triangle is a repeater)

[image: Permanent Circuit]

Unfortunately, this only works if you don't want to be able to turn it off again. If that's required, more resources are needed.

[image: Resource-heavy Circuit]

This requires a second line alongside the first one which applies power every 15 blocks (this can be extended to 29 blocks if the redstone power level doesn't matter, as power is applied in both directions).

Comment: Won't that lock the system...?

Comment: Updated with non-locking solution.